# How to get my sub navigation menu to go up?

Tags: html, css

Here's the problem:

[image]

I'm trying to get this sub navigation to go all the way up, and I'm not sure if something is blocking it, but I could use some help. I tried adding the bottom property to my "#subnav-content" selector and it didn't work. I need someone to look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#outer-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}

#content {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 85%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: gray;
}

#sidebar a {
  background-color: rgb(20, 15, 15);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar img {
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-right: .1em;
}

#subnav-content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 180px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>nested anchor links in divs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styling.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="outer-container">
    <div id="sidebar">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/play logo.webp" alt="play" id="play" height='25px' width='25px'><span>Play</span></a>
      <div id="subnav-content">
        <a href="#">Play</a>
        <a href="#">Live Chess</a>
        <a href="#">Daily Chess</a>
        <a href="#">Computer</a>
        <a href="#">Tournaments</a>
        <a href="#">4 Player Chess</a>
        <a href="#">Variants</a>
        <a href="#">Leaderboard</a>
        <a href="#">Library</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your parent (`#sidebar`) container relatively positioned in your CSS, and then make your `#subnav-content` absolutely positioned. This will make it so that when you position your `#subnav-content` element, it will be relative to it's parent container. Which, in this case, is your sidebar.

Give this a shot ([**Live Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/t9a5rh60/)):

```
#subnav-content{
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 15%;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 180px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**Edit**: Making amendments for your request in the comment, if you fix the position of the element, you can make the `#subnav-content` element take up the entire page.

Comment: How do I get the sub nav span the entire page going downwards? @GROVER.

Comment: @AdamBreslin You will have to use a `fixed` position. See updated answer.

Comment: It doesn't span the entire page going downwards. @GROVER.

Comment: I got it. I just displayed it as a table-cell for some reason that worked. @GROVER.

Answer (score 0):

Make sidebar `position: relative` and subnav-content `position: absolute` [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c7nkrLd5/)

```
#sidebar { position: relative }
#subnav-content { position: absolute }
```

Comment: how do I get the sub nav span the entire page? @iftikharyk